# QString password encrypt

Tags: xml, qt

I am trying to send a user name and password via a QString constructed XML. How can I decrypt the password and send it. So far in my function I have the following:

```
// Username
command_string += "<user>";
command_string += m_username;
command_string += "</user>";

// Password
command_string += "<password>";
command_string += m_password;
command_string += "</password>";
```

This displays the full password when sent to the server which is an obvious security issue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sending password is already an issue. Why do you need to send it?

Comment: Use hash to encrypt, Qt has some library [QCryptographicHash](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html#hash)

Comment: You should never send the actual password to the server (See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96556/151650 for why)! Instead, hash it like @Simon suggested und just use this hashed password on the server. Additionally, you should apply some kind of transport encryption like TLS to protect the data during the transfer. What exactly you use here depends on how the data is transfered and what capabilities the server and your client have.